# Kubernetes multi node cluster

Tags: kubernetes

In a kubernetes mutli node cluster, say with 1 master and 10 workers,

Can kubectl tool run in worker nodes also?

Can there be 2 masters on a k8s cluster also ?

How is kubernetes clusters fault tolerant , if 1 master node fails or has hardware issues?

Which platforms are offering such setups?

Answer (score 1):

> Can kubectl tool run in worker nodes also?

Yes.

> Can there be 2 masters on a k8s cluster also ?

Yes, one is a primary and another secondary.

> How is kubernetes clusters fault-tolerant, if 1 master node fails or has hardware issues?

This is something where you need to explore from [Set up High-Availability Kubernetes Masters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/highly-available-master/). Writing here will be redundant.